# A working clearfix for absolutely positioned children

Tags: html, css, clearfix

Consider the following code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="A">
        <div id="B" style="left: 0; position: absolute; top: 0;">... STUFF ...</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**A** turns out to have a height of 0, regardless of the size of **B** and its contents. I want **A** to have its height set appropriately according to what's inside **B**.

Is this possible to achieve with CSS ?

So far, I haven't found any way to do it, but I'm pretty sure CSS should be capable of handling this, it looks like an extremely trivial to do.

I know there are many posts about achieving clearfix, but they appear to be outdated. It's 2016 now, maybe there are new alternatives available.

*Important stuff: This is what I want to achieve, I didn't write that little layout and those style properties **by chance**. Please refrain from suggesting alternatives where the layout is different form the one I presented.*

Comment: Position:absolute takes element off the flow, so it is unseen by any other elements and there is nothing like clearing absolute or fixed element. Clearfix methods are about floatting element, Javascript could help you there but i do not know any script of that kind ready made ...

Comment: you want it only in css?. Can you use js?

Comment: @Thinker I would prefer for it to be in CSS.

Comment: @GCyrillus Oh ok, any way to force it back into the flow? I can't float those elements, because there can be many of them behind one another and they would stack side by side, which is not what I intend to do. I really don't want to solve this with JS.

Comment: Does each absolute positioned item (i.e. `#B`) have a variable width and height?

Comment: Well if the idea is to stack them but let them groww according to their content, you may use display:table; (wil shrink/expand to fit content, but will behave like block stacking on top of each others http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRLNJK

Comment: "Unclear what you're asking"... SO is worse everyday.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want A's height to match the content in B, you can do it by adding `display: list-item;` to A. `display: list-item;` generates block box for content.

```css
#A {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div id="B" style="left: 0; position: absolute; top: 0;">... STUFF ...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you rps, very interesting alternative, however it does not take into account elements like img's.